# Heap issue when using kotlin coroutine in a Batch process

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to call an API for each element in a list.

So I created below code which is an extension function:

```
suspend fun <T, V> Iterable<T>.customAsyncAll(method: suspend (T) -> V): Iterable<V> {
    val deferredList = mutableListOf<Deferred<V>>()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(dispatchers.io)
    forEach {
      val deferred = scope.async {
        try {
          method(it)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          log.error { "customAsyncAll Exception in $method method " + e.stackTraceToString())
          }
          throw e
        }
      }
      deferredList.add(deferred)
    }
    return deferredList.awaitAll()
  }
```

Call the code as:

```
val result = runBlocking{ list.customAsyncAll { apiCall(it) }.toList() }
```

I see error `posting Resource Exhausted event: Java heap space`. What is wrong with this code?

When an exception is thrown in one of the api calls, will the rest of the courouting async stuff be released or it still occupies heap space?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are passing a somewhat large list (50+ items). I do believe that making so many calls is the problem, and realistically speaking I don't think you will have any performance gain by opening more than 10 connections to the API at a time. Μy suggestion would be to limit the concurrent calls to any number of less than 20.

There are many ways to implement this, using Semaphore is my recommendation.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T, V> Iterable<T>.customAsyncAll(method: suspend (T) -> V): Iterable<V> {
    val deferredList = mutableListOf<Deferred<V>>()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    val sema = Semaphore(10)
    forEach {
      val deferred = scope.async {
        sema.withPermit {
          try {
            method(it)
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error { 
              "customAsyncAll Exception in $method method " 
                + e.stackTraceToString())
            }
            throw e
          }
        }
      }
      deferredList.add(deferred)
    }
    return deferredList.awaitAll()
  }
```

###### sidenote

Be sure to cancel any custom CouroutineScope you create after you are done with it, see [Custom usage](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/).

Comment: Also, another related question. How can I configure the threads like thread core pool, max pool, queue size etc incase of coroutines? Because coroutines finally use the underlying threads.